# Pass username & password from PHP to Apache

Tags: php, apache, authentication, kerberos

I have a loginform where users can login with two different accounts - one is a SolarisLDAP account and the other is an Active Directory account.
When the user tries to log in I want to find out which account he uses (which is not the problem).

If he's using the SolarisLDAP account, the authentication is done in PHP.
But if it is an AD account it must be passed to Apache (because I have to use the mod_auth_kerb to authenticate against our AD).

I wonder if this is possible in any way. Could I just set `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`, or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`, and that's it?

Or would it be a possibility to kinda do it via the headers or a redirect?

Hope you understand what I'm trying to do..

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if this is possible in any way.

Unfortunately - no.

Also note that passing whatever variables from PHP to Apache makes no sense in that context.
It is not PHP but *browser* you want to authenticate with Apache, and, obviously, you have no control of.

Comment: Huh? Where do I want to authenticate with the browser?

Comment: Well, it was unclear phrasing. Now, I hope, it makes more sense.

Comment: Duh, I'm not sure. I don't want to authenticate with apache but with an AD, through Apache mod_auth_kerb. Is this still "with" Apache?

The issue here is that I want to use _one_ loginform, regardless of which account the user is using, but I'm not able to use PHP to authenticate against AD. Thus, the AD-auth must be done with mod_auth_kerb and the SolarisLDAP-auth is handled through PHP.

Comment: I do perfectly understand what you want, don't bother to repeat. You can fake cookie based authentication (as long as secured resource stays in the same domain) but you can't do it for the Basic/Digest HTTP authentication used by Apache.

Comment: Well, ok, thank you then.

Seem like I'll have to do it different anyways, because SSO awaits me too :)

Answer (score -1):

This depends on which environment variables apache does set for the request. Do a

```
 var_dump($_SERVER);
```

to get a list of all available ones. Go through that list and find out which ones are related to the authentication. It's probably something non-standard, this is a general list: http://php.net/_SERVER, compare it with your `var_dump` output.

Also this might depend on [which Server-API (SAPI) you're using with PHP<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).